# Add gradient as a class in Tailwind css

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I want to add this style:

```
background: linear-gradient(10deg, #AF8800 4.03%, #AA9F1F 6.02%, #A7B334 6.01%)
```

... to tailwind to be able to add it as a `class` name. I know that in tailwind we can create classes like this:

```
bg-[red]
```

Question: How to do the same action as above with the  specified gradient?

Answer (score 2):

It is complex gradient so you have to use either arbitrary values or extend Tailwind configuration. Add CSS property almost as it is within square brackets - replace spaces with low dash `_`. Your class should looks like

```html
<div class="bg-[linear-gradient(10deg,#AF8800_4.03%,#AA9F1F_6.02%,#A7B334_6.01%)] p-10"></div>
```

If you have less than 3 colors included it may be separated between few "stop-color" classes

```html
<div class="p-10 bg-[linear-gradient(10deg,var(--tw-gradient-stops))] from-[#AF8800_4.03%] via-[#AA9F1F_6.02%] to-[#A7B334_6.01%]"></div>
```

*I've also created [this](https://github.com/czernika/tailwindcss-bggradient) package so you can use `bg-gradient-10` instead of `bg-[linear-gradient(10deg,var(--tw-gradient-stops))]`*

If you want to avoid arbitrary variants you may extend configuration for [background-image](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-image#basic-usage) or create static utility [plugin](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/plugins#static-utilities)

```js
const plugin = require('tailwindcss/plugin')

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        'my-gradient': 'linear-gradient(10deg, #AF8800 4.03%, #AA9F1F 6.02%, #A7B334 6.01%)'
      }
    },
  },
  plugins: [
     plugin(function({ addUtilities, addComponents, e, config }) {
      addUtilities({
        '.bg-my-uitility-gradient': {
          'background-image': 'linear-gradient(10deg, #AF8800 4.03%, #AA9F1F 6.02%, #A7B334 6.01%)',
        },
      })
    })
  ],
}
```

```html
<div class="p-10 bg-my-gradient"></div>

<div class="p-10 bg-my-uitility-gradient"></div>
```

[DEMO](https://play.tailwindcss.com/FxNJ4LQA8Z)

Comment: i try to add thi style to a svg path: `fill-[linear-gradient(10deg,#AF8800_4.03%,#AA9F1F_6.02%,#A7B334_6.01%)] `, but it does not work. How could i do this?

Answer (score 1):

you can easily use from and to in your class like

```html
<div class="bg-gradient-to-r from-cyan-500 to-blue-500"></div>
```

from that's snippet you can gradient from color cyan 500, to blue 500